# Await putfile never finishes flutter firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I'm currently getting an audio file's path on my devices using flutter file picker but when I try to upload it to storage the await never completes for the upload task. However, if I don't await for the uploadtask to finish I can see it in my bucket. What am I doing wrong

This is the upload to storage code

```
 final firebase_storage.Reference storageRef = firebase_storage
      .FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('audio.m4a');

  Future<void> uploadFile(String filePath) async {
    File file = File(filePath);
    print(file.path);
    firebase_storage.UploadTask task = storageRef.putFile(file);
    print(task);
    String url = await (await task).ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(url);
  }
```

This is the code for my button which calls the upload

```
 ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('Run Future',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
      onPressed: () {
          uploadFile(path)
           .then((value) => print("in builder"));
      },
 )))
```

Edit: So my file uploads fine but it never finishes the await. The download URL is never retrieved. I tried to listen to snapshots of the task but nothing ever gets printed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the other answer is correct. However, this is how I do such a task.

```
task = storageRef.putFile(_uniImage);
task.whenComplete(() {
  print("image uploaded");
});

url = await profReference.getDownloadURL();
Now, you can return this url, if you wish to. It is up to you.
```